# Irreducibility of polynomial in $\Bbb F_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

What can we say about the irreduciblity of $x^{q-1} + \cdots + 1 $ in $\Bbb F_p[x]$ where $p,q$ distinct primes?

In $\Bbb Z[x]$ we may apply a transformation and apply Eisenstein's criterion. But $\Bbb F_p$ has no more prime ideals.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{q-1}+x^{q-2}+\cdots+x+1$ is the $q$-th cyclotomic polynomial.
It is irreducible over $\Bbb F_p$ iff $p$ is a primitive root modulo $q$.
This is because adjoining the $q$-th roots is unity to $\Bbb F_p$
gives $\Bbb F_{p^k}$ where $k$ is the least integer with $q\mid
(p^k-1)$.

Comment: In other words, irreducibility $\Leftrightarrow q$ does not divide any of $p-1, p^2-1, ..., p^{q-2}-1$.